# Tabela não adiciona a ultima requisição

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, codeigniter

Bom dia guys,

Vou direto ao assunto... Eu tenho esse success do meu json onde valido a seguinte função:

```
 for(i=0; data.length>i ;i++)
        {   
                let cliente = data[i].item;
                let totais = {};
                data[i].item.forEach(i => {

                if(! totais[i.projeto])
                {
                   totais[i.projeto] = '';
                }
                 totais[i.projeto] = i.cliente ;
                });

                Object.keys(totais).forEach(l =>{
                    let clientes = totais[l];
                    $('#tabela').append('<table class="table table-light" id="table'+data[i].projeto+'"><thead class = "thead-dark"><tr><th>'+clientes+'-'+data[i].projeto+'</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></thead>');
                });

            for(j = 0; j < cliente.length; j++)
            {   

                $('#table'+data[i].projeto).append('<tbody><tr><td>'+cliente[j].nome+'</td><td>'+cliente[j].desc+'</td><td>'+cliente[j].type+'</td><td>'+cliente[j].start+'-'+cliente[j].end+'</td><td>'+cliente[j].duration+'</td><td class="ml-auto text-right"><buttom class="btn btn-primary mr-2 botao" id="edit"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></buttom><buttom class="btn btn-danger botao" id="remove"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i></i></buttom></td></tbody></table>');
                console.log(cliente[j].nome)
            }

        }
```

Porem não aparece a ultima opção na tabela, mas no console.log aparece o resultado. Como na imagem abaixo, alguém poderia me dar um norte do que pode ser feito?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O json está assim:

```
[{"projeto":"TimeSheet","item":[{"id":"8","nome":"TimeTrack","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o da time track","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"16\/08\/2019","end":"21\/08\/2019","duration":"120:00","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","usuarios":"Diego, Anderson"},{"id":"10","nome":"Dashboard","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o da dashboard","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"16\/08\/2019","end":"21\/08\/2019","duration":"20:00","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","usuarios":"Diego"},{"id":"11","nome":"Pacote","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o tela de pacote","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"19\/08\/2019","end":"22\/08\/2019","duration":"96:00","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","usuarios":"Diego, Anderson, Marcelo"}]},{"projeto":"Software","item":[{"id":"14","nome":"Software Line","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o da tela do software","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"16\/08\/2019","end":"22\/08\/2019","duration":"120:00","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"Software","usuarios":"Diego,"}]},{"projeto":"Aplicativo Mobile","item":[{"id":"13","nome":"Aplicativo Mobile","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o de um app","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"21\/08\/2019","end":"22\/08\/2019","duration":"24:00","cliente":"Marcelo","projeto":"Aplicativo Mobile","usuarios":"Diego, Anderson"}]}]
```

Comment: Talvez seja o `data.length>i, mude para `data.length>=i` e veja se funcionou.

Comment: Não funciona, ele para de percorrer meu value e só percorre meinha key.

Comment: Se tu printar o `i`, até que número ele vai? Do primeiro for

Comment: Ele vem o meu json... normal, a questão é que só não printa na tabela do marcelo, porem os dados dele vem tranquilamente.

Comment: E vai até o numero 2

Comment: Coloca na pergunta uma amostra do JSON.

Comment: @Sam, postei meu json.

Comment: "Última opção" que vc se refere seria uma linha abaixo de "Marcelo-Aplicativo Mobile"?

Comment: @sam isso, essa linha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que o código `data[i].projeto` pode vir com espaços, no caso de `Aplicativo Mobile`, existe um espaço entre as duas palavras, e ao atribuir isso a um `id` irá invalidar o id da tabela desta forma: `id="tableAplicativo Mobile"`. Um id não pode conter espaços.

Para resolver isso, basta remover possíveis espaços com um replace:

```
data[i].projeto.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

Então no id você fará:

```
id="table'+data[i].projeto.replace(/\s/g, '')+'"
```

E no `for` fará:

```
$('#table'+data[i].projeto.replace(/\s/g, ''))
```

Veja como fica:

```js
const data = [{"projeto":"TimeSheet","item":[{"id":"8","nome":"TimeTrack","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o da time track","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"16\/08\/2019","end":"21\/08\/2019","duration":"120:00","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","usuarios":"Diego, Anderson"},{"id":"10","nome":"Dashboard","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o da dashboard","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"16\/08\/2019","end":"21\/08\/2019","duration":"20:00","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","usuarios":"Diego"},{"id":"11","nome":"Pacote","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o tela de pacote","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"19\/08\/2019","end":"22\/08\/2019","duration":"96:00","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","usuarios":"Diego, Anderson, Marcelo"}]},{"projeto":"Software","item":[{"id":"14","nome":"Software Line","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o da tela do software","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"16\/08\/2019","end":"22\/08\/2019","duration":"120:00","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"Software","usuarios":"Diego,"}]},{"projeto":"Aplicativo Mobile","item":[{"id":"13","nome":"Aplicativo Mobile","desc":"Cria\u00e7\u00e3o de um app","info":"","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","start":"21\/08\/2019","end":"22\/08\/2019","duration":"24:00","cliente":"Marcelo","projeto":"Aplicativo Mobile","usuarios":"Diego, Anderson"}]}]

for(i=0; data.length>i ;i++)
  {   
          let cliente = data[i].item;
          let totais = {};
          data[i].item.forEach(i => {

          if(! totais[i.projeto])
          {
             totais[i.projeto] = '';
          }
           totais[i.projeto] = i.cliente ;
          });

          Object.keys(totais).forEach(l =>{
              let clientes = totais[l];
              $('#tabela').append('<table class="table table-light" id="table'+data[i].projeto.replace(/\s/g, '')+'"><thead class = "thead-dark"><tr><th>'+clientes+'-'+data[i].projeto+'</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></thead>');
          });

      for(j = 0; j < cliente.length; j++)
      {   

          $('#table'+data[i].projeto.replace(/\s/g, '')).append('<tbody><tr><td>'+cliente[j].nome+'</td><td>'+cliente[j].desc+'</td><td>'+cliente[j].type+'</td><td>'+cliente[j].start+'-'+cliente[j].end+'</td><td>'+cliente[j].duration+'</td><td class="ml-auto text-right"><buttom class="btn btn-primary mr-2 botao" id="edit"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></buttom><buttom class="btn btn-danger botao" id="remove"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i></i></buttom></td></tbody></table>');
      }

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="tabela"></div>
```

Comment: Show de bola amigo! Valeuzão, realmente, não prestei atenção nesse detalhe! Mais um vez, Obrigado!